# How can I get the reference count on a COM smart pointer?

Tags: com

I got hired at my current job at a salary 50% greater than I had been making because I was vaguely familiar with COM.  I'm assigned to a large code base that is stuck using COM because rewriting it with anything more modern would probably take a year.  So, I need to know more about COM than I do.

I have a smart object defined by this line:

```
_COM_SMARTPTR_TYPEDEF(IEDSEventLog, __uuidof(IEDSEventLog));
```

I would like to see the reference count on an IEDSEventLogPtr object so I can better understand the object's lifetime.  How can I get its reference count?

Comment: Why is it important? Generally, it's not except for debugging sometimes... However, if you call AddRef(), it's supposed to return the new ref count...but documentation says to only do it for debugging/testing purposes. So, if you call AddRef(), the return value should be +1 of before the call. Of course, call Release() afterwards...which then returns the new refcount. If you call AddRef/Release, the ref count of the object should be the original ref count of the object. But, you shouldn't make any reliances on it.

Comment: Precisely.  It's for debugging.  We've code which was written by people who understood COM but is being maintained by those, like me, who don't.

Comment: COM is still modern and still very much in use and the foundation of Windows.  There are lots of really really good books on COM that will help you to get an understanding of this brilliant technology.  It is not outdated it is just complex.

Answer (score 0):

As per  joseph Willcoxson comment

If you call AddRef(), it's supposed to return the new ref count...but documentation says to only do it for debugging/testing purposes. So, if you call AddRef(), the return value should be +1 of before the call. Of course, call Release() afterwards...which then returns the new refcount.

If you call AddRef/Release, the ref count of the object should be the original ref count of the object. But, you shouldn't make any reliances on it.